# Subsetting within variables using a loop in R

Tags: r

I'm relatively new to R and would be incredibly appreciative of any help.

I have survey data (items are called j01:j10) grouped into geographic areas (VISN), and there are stations (StaNo) within each area. The goal is to compare each station to the mean of the VISN excluding the particular station, and to do that for each item. Here is a small example set:

```
> visn<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
> station<-c(101, 102, 103, 201, 202, 203)
> j01<-c(2,3,4,2,3,4)
> j02<-c(3,2,5,4,2,3)
> data<-cbind(visn, station, j01, j02)
```

I have 2 functions already written (cliffs.d and sig), and I need subsetted data to pass to them. I have these subsets hard-coded (11,000+ lines of code) and I don't know how to use indexing or looping to condense.

Here is an example of what I have, for 1 comparison (station 101 compared to VISN 1 excluding station 101, for item j01):

```
>visn<-subset(data, VISN==1 & StaNo!="101", select=j01)
>station<-subset(data, StaNo=="101", select=j01)>
>a<-c(cliffs.d(station, visn))
>p<-c(sig(station, visn))
```

This is what I need (I only know how to express this in non-vectorized language):

```
for each item in c(j01:j10)
  for each station in station
     visn<-subset(data, visn==visn[i] & station!=stano[i], select=item[i]
     station<-subset(data, station==station[i], select=item[i]
     a<-c(a, cliffs.d(station, visn))
     p<-c(p, sig(station, visn))
```

I've spent days on this and I'll be incredibly thankful for any help or pushes in the right direction.

Comment: It's good that you've shared some example code, but why don't you also try to express in words what you are trying to achieve here, perhaps also showing us the expected output from your sample dataset.

Comment: I would but the output wouldn't be meaningful since the functions (cliffs.d and sig) need lots of cases to run. Maybe a broader explanation would help: the goal is to compare each station's responses to the rest of that station's VISN (excluding the station under consideration). So for each item, I need to go down the list of Stations and select (1) all responses to item X from Station Y, and (2) select all the responses from Station Y's VISN except for those from Station Y. So I'm comparing each station to everyone else in their VISN (geographic group).

Comment: These are the subsets I would want from the example set: for the first comparison (station 101 compared to visn 1 for j01) visn should be 3, 4, and station should be 2. For the second comparison on j01 (station 102 compared to visn 1) visn should be 2, 4, and station should be 3.

Comment: It might then be easier for you to find a solution in terms of a 'conventional' approach (i.e. 'non-vectorized'), which R also supports, such as `data <- as.data.frame(data); 
for (itemname in tail(colnames(data),-2)) {
 for (station in unique(data$station)) {
  print(sprintf("%s // %s",itemname,station))
}}`

Comment: Sorry, @rld01, but your comment made the problem even more confusing! In your "first" comparison station 101 (j01 == 2) must be compared with the mean of 102 (j01 == 3) and 103 (j01 == 4). So why (quote) "visn should be 3,4, and station should be 2" ?

Comment: @George, for the first comparison on j01, 101=2. My function needs the individual-level scores for VISN rather than a VISN mean, so for my function cliffs.d(station, visn), station=2 and visn=3, 4. (as opposed to the visn mean, which would be 3.5 in that comparison).

Comment: @texb, thank you, I didn't know that was possible.

Comment: I'm working on the non-vectorized solution using loops but I know loops usually run slowly in R (and they are) so any help with a vectorized solution would be fantastic as well.